Difference between ～ないかな and ～ないのかな
I am aware of ～ないかな construction but I am wondering how ～ないのかな works.
From the recent Oshi no ko chapter, Mem was about to make an announcement that she has been doing サバ読み and wanted to apologize. She was unsure what will happen next. Ruby reassured her and said:

そんな芸能界を巧みに渡ってた感性と一度の炎上も無く綱渡りをしてきたその嗅覚で今回の件もどうにかならないのかなあ?

Based on context, 今回の件もどうにかならないのかなあ is understood as "I hope it goes well" but I am not sure about what nuance の adds in this sentence.

That's a plain explanatory-の used to seek clarification. Explaining the difference in English is always difficult for me, but I'll try:

明日は休みにならないかな。
I hope it's gonna be a day off tomorrow.
→ The speaker is simply hoping for something.

明日は休みにならないのかな。
Won't tomorrow be a day off? / I'm starting to wonder if it'll be a day off tomorrow.
→ The speaker is wondering what's going on.

それでどうにかならないかな？
Won't it work somehow?
→ This sounds like a simple suggestion.

それでどうにかならないのかな？
Won't it work somehow? (If not, why? I'm wondering.)
→ The speaker is trying to understand the situation at hand.


